# Чтение атрибутов из MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, manifest

При компиляции **Java** приложения вписываются данные в **MANIFEST.MF** файл которые потом должны использоваться при запуске приложения. Манифест файл содержит всё необходимое после компиляции.

Часть кода из Ant скрипта:

```
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
    <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${build.tstamp}" />
    <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <attribute name="Implementation-URL" value="http://example.com/" />
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="src.app.MyApp" />
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.libs}" />
</manifest>
```

Содержимое манифеста после компиляции:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.1
Created-By: 1.8.0_151-b12 (Oracle Corporation)
Built-By: Rootware
Built-Date: 2018-09-21 21:59:11
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0.0
Implementation-URL: http://example.com/
Main-Class: src.app.MyApp
Class-Path: ../libs/c3p0-0.9.6-pre1.jar ../libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar 
 ../libs/mchange-commons-java-0.2.12.jar ../libs/mysql-connector-java-
 5.1.46.jar
```

Код Java для чтения атрибутов:

```
private static void getBuildDate()
{
    try (InputStream stream = MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"))
    {
        final Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.read(stream);
        final Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();

        if (attributes.getValue("Built-Date") != null)
            BUILD_DATE = attributes.getValue("Built-Date");
        else
            _log.info("Null attribute.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

При чтении атрибута **Built-Date** всегда *null*. Подскажите, что я делаю не так при чтении манифеста? Если попытаться читать **Implementation-Version**, то выводится **0.9.6-pre1** версия первой библиотеки указанной в списке библиотек из **Class-Path** списка.

Comment: странный `MANIFEST`. никогда не видел его в xml. всегда в формате `key=value`. Проверьте, может не тот `minefest` попадается Вам. Возможно из библиотеки.

Comment: @Tsyklop Это код из Ant скрипта. На выходе, получается нормальный файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не пытайтесь читать `MANIFEST.MF` как ресурс, поскольку у вас в classpath может быть несколько JAR файлов и у каждого из них будет свой `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Чтение `MANIFEST.MF` в рантайме - это путь к багам и к неопределённому поведению вашей программы. Говорю из личного опыта работы в проекте, где кто-то тоже решил так делать. Вместо этого создайте файл `properties` во время сборки и записывайте туда дату сборки.

Не знаю как это сделать в Ant. В Maven это делается достаточно просто:

1. Создаёте ещё одну директорию ресурсов `src/main/resources-filtered` и в ней, скажем, `com/example/myprog/build.properties` следующего содержания:

   ```
   build.date=${build.date}
   ```
2. В `pom.xml` в секции `<build>` прописываете обе директории ресурсов и в какой из них включён режим обработки ресурсов во время их копирования:

   ```
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       </resource>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   ```
3. Там же в `pom.xml` в секции `<properties>` прописываете два новых параметра:

   ```
   <build.date>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.date>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
   ```

Далее, у себя в коде, открываете ресурс `com/example/myprog/build.properties`, создаёте из него экземпляр `Properties` и читаете от тудё всё что вы туда записали.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось вот так для Ant: `<concat destfile="${build.classes.version}/version.properties">Version=${build.version}${line.separator}BuildDate=${build.timestamp}</concat>`. Добавьте к ответу.